# How to make Kendo dropdown select always visible inside Kendo grid

Tags: select, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to put a simple select inside a Kendo grid, but am having no luck. Select is not showing. Any idea what I need to do?

Here is my code:

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table").kendoGrid({
            autoBind: true,
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: false,
            selectable: false,
            filterable: false
        });
    });
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('select').kendoDropDownList();

 });
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="min-height:400px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ALL Vaults</th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>

                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>

                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>option 1</option>
                    <option>option 2</option>

                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rFDD6/458/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you want with this configuration. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rFDD6/459/)

```
function DropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<select data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"><option>option 1</option><option>option 2</option></select>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList();
}
```

Comment: The problem is here because it does not see select, only when clicked:(

Comment: @play2web the dropdown cannot be always visible your scenario is not supported http://www.telerik.com/forums/put-all-rows-into-edit-mode. My suggestion is the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619142/how-to-update-kendo-grid-row-from-window/28633914#28633914