# Create a custom edit popup for a dynamic grid in Kendo UI using kendo.Observable() object?

Tags: dynamic, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-observable

Can somebody tell me, following scenario can achieve using Kendo UI ??

I am making a dynamic grid. Because my data source is dynamic. 
Then I need a custom edit popup for update field.

In hear what I done is I make a new `kendo.Observable()` object and make the input fields and then try to bind the data that received for the template.

But this method is not working.
Can someone tell me there is a way to achieve this ??

If you need more info I can update this..
Thank you.

**Edit**

update code : 
This is my dynamic grid.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({ // this will be dynamic data       source}),
editable: {
                mode: "popup",
                template: kendo.template($("#myCustomPopup").html())
            },



columns: leadFields });
```

This is my custom template.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myCustomPopup">
    #console.log(data);#
    <div id="mySecondCustomPopup">
        <table data-template="myCustomFieldsTemplate" data-bind="source: dataField"></table>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myCustomFieldsTemplate">
 // in here I try to make field using kendo.Observable() object
<script>
```

Here is my `observable` object

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({dataField: leadArray});

kendo.bind($("#mySecondCustomPopup"), viewModel);
```

If I explain this more I try to bind different view model to update popup via `kendo observable` object.
Can I do something like that ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619142/how-to-update-kendo-grid-row-from-window/28633914#28633914

Answer (score 1):

The [editable.template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-editable.template) option of the grid allows you to customize the popup editor. Here is some sample code:

```
<script id="popup-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <h3>Edit Person</h3>
  <p>
    <label>Name:<input data-bind="value:name" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Age:<input data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="value:age" /></label>
  </p>
</script>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    { command: "edit" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    schema: {
      model: { id: "id" }
    }
  },
  editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: In my situation this method is not suit. Because My data source is dynamic . In here we have static fields. My fields are dynamic. What I want to know is Can I trigger a update popup and bind a 'kendo.Observable()' object to that update popup ??

Comment: I added some code to question. It will help to you.

Comment: I have a another question. Can you please look at this ...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623574/bind-kendovalidator-object-to-custom-grid-update-popup